# Smokeping monitoring IP address and port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port, monitoring, tcpip

I have successfully install smokeping on my Ubuntu Karmic machine and am monitoring servers.
I need to be able to monitor an IP address and a port, can someone tell me how I do that?

I looked into Smokeping::probes::TCPPing but I cannot find how to install TCPPing

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get tcpping from [vdberg.org](http://www.vdberg.org/~richard/tcpping).  An alternative monitoring solution is [etherape](http://etherape.sourceforge.net/).  It's in your ubuntu repository & is easy to use & gives the information you want.

[image]

Another alternative is [nmap](http://nmap.org).  Tere is a nice GUI for it: [zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/), which can create a network topology map.  Both are in your repository.

[image: zenmap]

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note on tcpping which does not work anymore with recent traceroute binaries.

A newer version of the script can be grabbed at https://github.com/deajan/tcpping

Will work with Linux and BSD (tested with linux traceroute traceroute 2.0.22 and FreeBSD traceroute 1.4a12).

This will hopefully save some headaches on setting up a TCPPing probe on smokeping :)